# Verification: $G=\mathbb{Z}_{p^3}\times \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$, how many subgroups in $G$ are with order $p^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups

The OP is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4684422/number-of-subgroups-of-order-p2-in-mathbbz-p3-oplus-mathbbz-p2?noredirect=1#comment9907712_4684422), but this post was deleted by the author. So I put it here. If $G=\mathbb{Z}_{p^3}\times \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$, how many subgroups in $G$ are with the order $p^2$?

Here is my solution:

Since $G$ is Abelian, its subgroups are either cyclic or non-cyclic. For cyclic subgroups case, first we count the number of elements whose order is $p^2$, since each them can generate a cyclic subgroup with order $p^2$. For an arbitrary element $g\in G$, we write it as $g=(x,y), x\in \mathbb{Z}_{p^3}, y\in \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$. If we solely look at the first component $x$, there are
$p^3-p^2$ generators for $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3}=\langle1\rangle$, and each generator has an order of $p^3$, but their order are greater than what we need. We discard them, so the remaining $p^3-(p^3-p^2)=p^2$ elements are with order $1, p,$ or $p^2$.

$\mathbb{Z}_{p^3}$ has a unique subgroup $\langle p\rangle$ with order $p^2$, and $\langle p\rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$, hence, there are $p^2-p$ generators for $\langle p\rangle$. Since the first component $x$ has $p^2-p$ choices with order $p^2$, and the order of the second component $y$ is always a factor of $p^2$. Therefore, the second component $y$ has $p^2$ choices. There are $(p^2-p)p^2$ combinations for this Case.$A$.

Similarly, if we solely look at the second component $y$, there are $p^2-p$ generators for $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$, and each generator has an order of $p^2$. For the first component $x$, we have shown in the beginning, there are $p^3-(p^3-p^2)=p^2$ elements are with order $1, p,$ or $p^2$. So there are $p^2(p^2-p)$ combinations for this Case.$B$.

**BUT**, there are repeated countings in Case.$A$ and Case.$B$. Those repeated countings are the elements with order for both the first component $|x|=p^2$ and the second component $|y|=p^2$, which are $|A\cap B|=(p^2-p)(p^2-p)$ cases.

So there are totaly

$$\begin{align}|A\cup B|&=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|\\
\\
&=(p^2-p)p^2+p^2(p^2-p)-(p^2-p)(p^2-p)\\
\\
&=(p^2-p)(p^2+p)\end{align}$$

distinct elements with order $p^2$. Each element generates a cyclic subgroup with order $p^2$, hence $(p^2-p)(p^2+p)$ cyclic subgroups with order $p^2$. **BUT**, they are counted repeatedly. Since for each cyclic subgroup with order $p^2$, it contains $p^2-p$ generators inside its own group, so we need to divide this factor.

$$\frac{(p^2-p)(p^2+p)}{p^2-p}=p^2+p$$

There are totally $p^2+p$ distinct cyclic subgroups with order $p^2$.

For non-cyclic subgroup case, there is only one subgroup with order $p^2$, which is $\langle p^2\rangle\times\langle p\rangle$.

In conclusion, there are totally $p^2+p+1$ subgroups with order $p^2$.

Comment: That looks right, but what is your question?

Comment: No, I don't have questions. I wrote an answer but the OP was deleted. So I post it here for a solution verification.

Comment: Try making your question more specific. See the fourth paragraph of [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35663/dont-close-solution-verification-as-dupe-instead-remove-questions-with-the-tag) for an example. Ask about a step of the proof that concerns you, for example.

Comment: No, this is not a question, this is an answer to the OP, which has been deleted by the author. Can you undelete the OP?

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: Do you read my above replies? I said I answered the OP but OP was deleted by the author. So what categrory should I choose? @BillDubuque https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4684422/number-of-subgroups-of-order-p2-in-mathbbz-p3-oplus-mathbbz-p2?noredirect=1#comment9907712_4684422

Comment: [Will be deleted soon] Are you a grad student or professor or..?